# Mongodb - aggregation of subdocument and update with the result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following problem. I have found and summarized each value in a subdocument.
It gives the following `[ { _id: 551fb140e4b04589d8997213, sumOfpeople: 342 } ]`

I want to take the `sumOfpeople` and insert it to the same House( the same req.params.house_id)

```
House.aggregate([
                    { $match: {
                        id: req.params.house_id
                    }},
                    { $unwind: '$people' }, // unwind creates a doc for every array element
                    { $group: { 
                        _id: '$_id',
                        sumOfpeople: { $sum: '$people.nr'}
                    }}
                ], function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        return;
                    }


                    console.log(result);
                });
```

This is the model that I want insert the result after the aggregation into.

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('House', {

  id: String,
  people: [{
    id: String, 
    nr: Number 
  }],
  sumOfpeople: Number //this is the field that I want to update after the aggregation 

});
```

I have tried to use $set : {sumOfpeople: { $sum: '$people.nr'}}. 
Is it possible to use $set inside an aggregation, or how can it be solved otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way in MongoDB to write results directly into an existing document while doing an aggregation.

You've got 2 options:

1. retrieve the results in your application code, and then in a second query update the document.
2. use the `$out` operator, that will write the results of the aggregation into a new collection. This operation will delete all documents in the results collection and insert the new one. ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/ )